# Vue Jest Testing await in loop

Tags: vue.js, asynchronous, async-await, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm pretty new in unit testing and I'm having some issues writing a function test for await in a loop.

code to test:

```
export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',
  setup() {
    const count = ref<number>(0);

    function foo(count: number, delay: number): Promise<void> {
      const resolver = async (resolve: () => void) => {
    
        count.value = count;

        while (count.value >= 0) {
          await yoo();
          await wait(delay);
          
          count.value -= 1;
        }
      }
      
      return new Promise<void>(resolver);
    }
    
    async function yoo() {
      // something
      await koo();
      // something else
    }

    function wait(waitTime: number): Promise<void> {
      const resolver = (resolve: () => void) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, waitTime);
      };

      return new Promise(resolver);
    }
  }
}
```

test:

```
let wrapper = mount(MyComponent);
let promise: Promise<void>;
let count = 5;

jest.useFakeTimers();

beforeAll(() => {
  promise = wrapper.vm.foo(count, 100);
})

test(`count value decreases at each iteration`, async () => {
  while (wrapper.vm.count >= 0) {
    const prevCountValue = wrapper.vm.count;

    await flushPromises();
    jest.runAllTimers();

    expect(wrapper.vm.count).toBe(prevCountValue - 1);
  }
}
```

Writing the test in this way breaks due to jest.setTimeout.Error:
[image]

Any ideas on what is the correct way to write this test?

Comment: This totally depends on how long yoo takes. You need to apply runAllTimers multiple times because new timeouts are created. I guess the most straightforward way would be to not test this with fake timeouts but with smaller real ones.

Comment: @EstusFlask but it is running multiple times as it's in a while loop...